# I am trying to build a neural network with one neuron using the pytorch library. It keeps giving me an error

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to build a neural network with one neuron using the pytorch library. This is my code (the error is at the bottom)

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_train = np.array([random.randint(1,1000) for x in range(1000)], dtype = np.float32)
y_train = np.array([int(num*3+1) for num in x_train], dtype = np.float32)

x_test = np.array([random.randint(1,1000) for x in range(1000)], dtype = np.float32)
y_test = np.array([int(num*3+1) for num in x_train], dtype = np.float32)

X_train = torch.from_numpy(x_train)
Y_train = torch.from_numpy(y_train)

plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
plt.scatter(X_train, Y_train)
plt.show()

X_test = torch.from_numpy(x_test)
Y_test = torch.from_numpy(y_test)

input_size = 1
hidden_size = 1
output_size = 1
learning_rate = 0.1


w1 = torch.rand(input_size, hidden_size, requires_grad = True)
b1 = torch.rand(hidden_size, output_size, requires_grad = True)



for i in range(100):
    y_pred = X_train.mm(w1).clamp(min = 0).add(b1)
    loss = (Y_train-y_pred).pow(2).sum()

    loss.backward()

    with torch.no_grad():
        w1-=w1.grad*learning_rate
        b1 -= b1.grad*learning_rate
        w1.grad.zero_()
        b1.grad.zero_()
```

When I run this code, it gives me a runtime error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-5142b17ecfff> in <module>
     32 
     33 for i in range(100):
---> 34     y_pred = X_train.mm(w1).clamp(min = 0).add(b1)
     35     loss = (Y_train-y_pred).pow(2).sum()
     36 

RuntimeError: matrices expected, got 1D, 2D tensors at C:\w\1\s\windows\pytorch\aten\src\TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:192
```

What is wrong with that line of code and how to make it work as planned.

Comment: see `torch.unsqueeze()`

Comment: I used torch.unsqueeze and then ran the function. It did not show any error. However when I printed w1, it showed a nan object. How do I fix that error?

Comment: I think that would be a new question. You have Nan values because they are infinity. The training runs, but the predictions increase to a level that Python turns them into Nan because they're too big. But like I said : there should be one problem per thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`torch` expects 2D input, so you need to add a new dimension to your inputs tensors.

```
X_train = torch.from_numpy(x_train[..., np.newaxis])
X_test = torch.from_numpy(x_test[..., np.newaxis])
```

As someone commented above, you can also use `torch.unsqueeze`:

```
for i in range(100):
    y_pred = torch.unsqueeze(X_train, 1).mm(w1).clamp(min = 0).add(b1)
    loss = (Y_train-y_pred).pow(2).sum()
```

Both do the same. The former applies it to the `numpy` arrays, and the latter does it on the `torch` tensors. Both will result in this shape, which is the correct format for `torch`:

```
Out[13]: torch.Size([1000, 1])
```

Comment: I used torch.unsqueeze and then ran the function. It did not show any error. However when I printed w1, it showed a nan object. How do I fix that error?